# Passing Variables into template from Function

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Im using @ViewChild to pass a value to a child templates function - basically the parent passes a value to the transition() function below and it works no problem passing it to the console log but i want the value to update in the template where it says "THE VALUE IS {{ value }}" but it is just staying blank.. any ideas ?

```
            import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

            @Component({
            selector: 'reptilehaus-loader',
            template: `<div class="loader">THE VALUE IS {{ value }}</div>`,
            styles: [`
            .loader {
            background-color: white;
            height: 100px;
            width:100px;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            color: black;
            z-index:99999;
            }
            `]
            })


            export class TransitionComponent  {

                value: string;

                    constructor() {}

                    transition(value) {
                        console.log(value);
                    }


            }
```

The parent view

```
            import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
            import {ProjectsMainApi} from '../../../services/projects-main';
            import 'rxjs/Rx';
            import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
            import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
            import {CanDeactivate, RouteTree} from '@angular/router';
            import {TransitionComponent} from '../../PageLoader/TransitionComponent';
            declare var jQuery: any;


            // <a class="project-display-matrice" *ngFor="let projekt of project | async" [routerLink]="['ProjectDetail', { projectlink: projekt.slug }]" >

            @Component({
                selector: 'projects',
                template:
                    `<div> template here  </div>
                    </a><loader></loader>`,
                directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,TransitionComponent]
            })

            export class ProjectsListComponent implements CanDeactivate, OnInit {

                elementRef: ElementRef;
                project: Observable<any>;

                @ViewChild(TransitionComponent) transitionComponent: TransitionComponent;


                constructor() {
                }
                ngOnInit() {

                }

                routerCanDeactivate(currTree?: RouteTree, futureTree?: RouteTree): Promise<boolean> {
                   console.log('PROJECT LIST');
                   // console.log('Item: ', currTree);
                   this.transitionComponent.transition("sdfsfsdf");       
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        jQuery('.loader').addClass('show');
                        setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000);
                    });
                }

                changeRoute() {

                    alert('test');

                }

            }
```

Basically whenever someone clicks a route routerCanDeactivate is supposed to create a delay and show the loading component but I am pretty lost on how to accomplish this so I have probably gone totally the wrong direction... basicaly when a user clicks a link I want a div to transition across the screen with my logo and disappear when the page is ready.

Currently routercandeactive is just passing a string to the function in my childview aka the loader using  this.transitionComponent.transition("sdfsfsdf");

Comment: Why don't you use bindings to pass values from parent to children. I don't see enoigh context to be sure what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Im new to ng2 so I havent made my way onto bindings yet. What I am trying to do it make a preloader so basically when a user navigates to a parent page i want to display the above component for 2 seconds then remove a class using timeout

Comment: Uhm, that's quite abstract. Can you please provide more code that shows how stuff is connected?

Comment: Yeah sorry im probably not explaining it well.. I have updated with more code and some info

Comment: I made an attempt. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template binding to get a value passed and updated from parent to children:

```ts
      @Component({
        selector: '...',
        directives: [TransitionComponent]
        template: '<reptilehaus-loader [value]="transition"></reptilehaus-loader>'
      })
      export class ProjectsListComponent implements CanDeactivate, OnInit {
            transition:any;
            elementRef: ElementRef;
            project: Observable<any>;

            routerCanDeactivate(currTree?: RouteTree, futureTree?: RouteTree): Promise<boolean> {
               console.log('PROJECT LIST');
               // console.log('Item: ', currTree);
               this.transition = "sdfsfsdf";       
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    jQuery('.loader').addClass('show');
                    setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000);
                });
            }

            changeRoute() {
                alert('test');
            }
        }
```

```ts
       export class TransitionComponent  {
            @Input() value: string;
       }
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter.. once again you have taught me something :) just out of interest how is the best way to create a preloader in ng2 in your opinion.. i havent seen a lot about it online yet

Comment: Not sure what "preloader" means :D. Is it a spinner that shows while loading? If it is for application loading then there should be an answer from me with a primitive example. If it is for route changes then there is at least one other answer. I had to look it up. First I need to know what you mean by "preloader".

Comment: Basically when I navigate to a different page sometimes there  is a lag while waiting for the data from the API.. Its usually only very slight but I would rather show a div slide across the screen that have that lag on each page load, again it is only very slight but the perfectionist in me would rather show my logo

Comment: So yeah I guess a route based loader/fullscreen div with logo

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution out there. There will soon *again* come a new router and there is also the animation module coming soon. I guess it makes more sense to investigate when these are out. I guess the router will provide animation support for this use case out of the box eventually.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that.. so I guess the best way is to use jquery to add a class using  routerCanDeactivate ?

Comment: Adding a class shouldn't need jQuery (which should be avoided with Angular2). The problem is more to get hooks when the preloader should be shown and when it should be hidden.

Comment: I see. Im using a couple of jquery plugins and I have another question regarding them that I have just posted here.. It would be great to get your feedback on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747223/angular-2-jquery-plugin-issue-when-navigate-away-then-back-to-page

Comment: I guess I have to pass. I don't know much about jQuery.